# Tensorflow 2 -Probability: ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported numpy type: NPY_INT)

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

This is a mysterious error --to me-- that keeps propping up.

For a reproducible example, you can find the Jupyter Notebook here: https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter5_LossFunctions/Ch5_LossFunctions_TFP.ipynb) -- Chapter 5 (Loss Functions).

Conveniently, in this example, the data are artificial and constructed on the fly.

The part of the code that creates the problem is the following (I am running tensorflow 2):

```
# Code for creating artificial "dummy" data
# This is a common strategy for testing our models
# before applying it to real-world data



num_data = 100
X_data = (0.025 * tfd.Normal(loc=0.,scale=1.).sample(sample_shape=num_data))
Y_data = (0.5 * X_data + 0.01 * tfd.Normal(loc=0.,scale=1.).sample(sample_shape=num_data))

tf_var_data = tf.nn.moments(X_data, axes=0)[1]
covar = tfp.stats.covariance(X_data,Y_data, sample_axis=0, event_axis=None)
ls_coef = covar / tf_var_data

[
    X_data_, Y_data_, ls_coef_,
] = [
    X_data.numpy(), Y_data.numpy(), ls_coef.numpy(),
]

ls_intercept_ = Y_data_.mean() - ls_coef_ * X_data_.mean()

obs_stdev = tf.sqrt(
        tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.squared_difference(Y_data_, tf.reduce_mean(Y_data_, axis=0)),
                      axis=0))

# Let's define the log probability of the bayesian regression function
def finance_posterior_log_prob(X_data_, Y_data_, alpha, beta, sigma):
    """
    Our posterior log probability, as a function of states

    Args:
      alpha_: scalar, taken from state of the HMC
      beta_: scalar, taken from state of the HMC
      sigma_: scalar, the standard deviation of , taken from state of the HMC
    Returns: 
      Scalar sum of log probabilities
    Closure over: Y_data, X_data
    """
    rv_std = tfd.Uniform(name="std", low=0., high=100.)
    rv_beta = tfd.Normal(name="beta", loc=0., scale=100.)
    rv_alpha = tfd.Normal(name="alpha", loc=0., scale=100.)

    mean = alpha + beta * X_data_
    rv_observed = tfd.Normal(name="obs", loc=mean, scale=sigma)

    return (
        rv_alpha.log_prob(alpha) 
        + rv_beta.log_prob(beta) 
        + rv_std.log_prob(sigma)
        + tf.reduce_sum(rv_observed.log_prob(Y_data_))
    )

number_of_steps = 30000
burnin = 5000

# Set the chain's start state.
initial_chain_state = [
    tf.cast(1.,dtype=tf.float32) * tf.ones([], name='init_alpha', dtype=tf.float32),
    tf.cast(0.01,dtype=tf.float32) * tf.ones([], name='init_beta', dtype=tf.float32),
    tf.cast(obs_stdev,dtype=tf.float32) * tf.ones([], name='init_sigma', dtype=tf.float32)
]

# Since HMC operates over unconstrained space, we need to transform the
# samples so they live in real-space.
# Beta and sigma are 100x and 10x of alpha, approximately, so apply Affine scalar bijector
# to multiply the unconstrained beta and sigma by 100x and 10x to get back to 
# the problem space
unconstraining_bijectors = [
    tfp.bijectors.Identity(), #alpha
    tfp.bijectors.Shift(100.), #beta
    tfp.bijectors.Scale(10.),  #sigma
]

# Define a closure over our joint_log_prob.
unnormalized_posterior_log_prob = lambda *args: finance_posterior_log_prob(X_data_, Y_data_, *args)

step_size = 0.5

# Defining the HMC
kernel=tfp.mcmc.TransformedTransitionKernel(
    inner_kernel=tfp.mcmc.HamiltonianMonteCarlo(
        target_log_prob_fn=unnormalized_posterior_log_prob,
        num_leapfrog_steps=2,
        step_size=step_size,
        state_gradients_are_stopped=True),        
    bijector=unconstraining_bijectors)

kernel = tfp.mcmc.SimpleStepSizeAdaptation(
    inner_kernel=kernel, num_adaptation_steps=int(burnin * 0.8))

# Sampling from the chain.
[
    alpha, 
    beta, 
    sigma
], kernel_results = tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
    num_results = number_of_steps,
    num_burnin_steps = burnin,
    current_state=initial_chain_state,
    kernel=kernel,
    name='HMC_sampling'
) 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-b2e46a99062a> in <module>
     21     current_state=initial_chain_state,
     22     kernel=kernel,
---> 23     name='HMC_sampling'
     24 ) 
     25 

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\sample.py in sample_chain(num_results, current_state, previous_kernel_results, kernel, num_burnin_steps, num_steps_between_results, trace_fn, return_final_kernel_results, parallel_iterations, name)
    357                                             trace_fn(*state_and_results)),
    358         # pylint: enable=g-long-lambda
--> 359         parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations)
    360 
    361     if return_final_kernel_results:

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\internal\util.py in trace_scan(loop_fn, initial_state, elems, trace_fn, parallel_iterations, name)
    393         body=_body,
    394         loop_vars=(0, initial_state, trace_arrays),
--> 395         parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations)
    396 
    397     stacked_trace = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda x: x.stack(), trace_arrays)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    572                   func.__module__, arg_name, arg_value, 'in a future version'
    573                   if date is None else ('after %s' % date), instructions)
--> 574       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    575 
    576     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_value_notice_to_docstring(

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py in while_loop_v2(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, maximum_iterations, name)
   2489       name=name,
   2490       maximum_iterations=maximum_iterations,
-> 2491       return_same_structure=True)
   2492 
   2493 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py in while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, name, maximum_iterations, return_same_structure)
   2725                                               list(loop_vars))
   2726       while cond(*loop_vars):
-> 2727         loop_vars = body(*loop_vars)
   2728         if try_to_pack and not isinstance(loop_vars, (list, _basetuple)):
   2729           packed = True

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\internal\util.py in _body(i, state, trace_arrays)
    382 
    383     def _body(i, state, trace_arrays):
--> 384       state = loop_fn(state, elems_array.read(i))
    385       trace_arrays = tf.nest.pack_sequence_as(trace_arrays, [
    386           a.write(i, v) for a, v in zip(

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\sample.py in _trace_scan_fn(state_and_results, num_steps)
    341           body_fn=kernel.one_step,
    342           initial_loop_vars=list(state_and_results),
--> 343           parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations)
    344       return next_state, current_kernel_results
    345 

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\internal\util.py in smart_for_loop(loop_num_iter, body_fn, initial_loop_vars, parallel_iterations, name)
    315           body=lambda i, *args: [i + 1] + list(body_fn(*args)),
    316           loop_vars=[np.int32(0)] + initial_loop_vars,
--> 317           parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations
    318       )[1:]
    319     result = initial_loop_vars

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    572                   func.__module__, arg_name, arg_value, 'in a future version'
    573                   if date is None else ('after %s' % date), instructions)
--> 574       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    575 
    576     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_value_notice_to_docstring(

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py in while_loop_v2(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, maximum_iterations, name)
   2489       name=name,
   2490       maximum_iterations=maximum_iterations,
-> 2491       return_same_structure=True)
   2492 
   2493 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py in while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, name, maximum_iterations, return_same_structure)
   2725                                               list(loop_vars))
   2726       while cond(*loop_vars):
-> 2727         loop_vars = body(*loop_vars)
   2728         if try_to_pack and not isinstance(loop_vars, (list, _basetuple)):
   2729           packed = True

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\internal\util.py in <lambda>(i, *args)
    313       return tf.while_loop(
    314           cond=lambda i, *args: i < loop_num_iter,
--> 315           body=lambda i, *args: [i + 1] + list(body_fn(*args)),
    316           loop_vars=[np.int32(0)] + initial_loop_vars,
    317           parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\simple_step_size_adaptation.py in one_step(self, current_state, previous_kernel_results)
    378         reduced_log_accept_prob = reduce_logmeanexp(
    379             log_accept_prob,
--> 380             axis=prefer_static.range(num_reduce_dims))
    381         # reduced_log_accept_prob must broadcast into step_size_part on the
    382         # left, so we do an additional reduction over dimensions where their

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\math\generic.py in reduce_logmeanexp(input_tensor, axis, keepdims, name)
    109     lse = tf.reduce_logsumexp(input_tensor, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims)
    110     n = prefer_static.size(input_tensor) // prefer_static.size(lse)
--> 111     log_n = tf.math.log(tf.cast(n, lse.dtype))
    112     return lse - log_n
    113 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    178     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    179     try:
--> 180       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    181     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    182       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\math_ops.py in cast(x, dtype, name)
    746       # allows some conversions that cast() can't do, e.g. casting numbers to
    747       # strings.
--> 748       x = ops.convert_to_tensor(x, name="x")
    749       if x.dtype.base_dtype != base_type:
    750         x = gen_math_ops.cast(x, base_type, name=name)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1348 
   1349     if ret is None:
-> 1350       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1351 
   1352     if ret is NotImplemented:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\tensor_conversion_registry.py in _default_conversion_function(***failed resolving arguments***)
     50 def _default_conversion_function(value, dtype, name, as_ref):
     51   del as_ref  # Unused.
---> 52   return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
     53 
     54 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    256   """
    257   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
--> 258                         allow_broadcast=True)
    259 
    260 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    264   ctx = context.context()
    265   if ctx.executing_eagerly():
--> 266     t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    267     if shape is None:
    268       return t

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     94       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
     95   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 96   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
     97 
     98 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported numpy type: NPY_INT).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem seems to come from

kernel = tfp.mcmc.SimpleStepSizeAdaptation(
    inner_kernel=kernel, num_adaptation_steps=int(burnin * 0.8))

in another similar example, I got same error. if you skip this line, it works.